# How do I add an element to array in reducer in Redux when the array does not yet exist?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

I have a code sandbox to demo an issue I am having with Redux and React.

https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-3edy8

Basically this reducer does not work:

```
const initialState = {
  byId: {}
};

function addReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "RECEIVE_DATA":
      return {
        ...state,
        byId: {
          ...state.byId,
          [action.payload.id]: [
            ...state.byId[action.payload.id],
            action.payload.data
          ]
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default addReducer;
```

here is the action:

```
import { RECEIVE_DATA } from "./actionTypes";

export function action() {
  return {
    type: RECEIVE_DATA,
    payload: {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 2),
      data: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)
    }
  };
}
```

In my own app it throws an error like `state.byId[action.payload.id]` is not iterable which is true. But how do I push values to an array that does not yet exist because I do not know the `id`?

I thought the issue might be solved by changing the `initialState` or perhaps there is a function I am not aware of that allows me to either create an `array` or `push` to it.

Comment: So if, for example, your action's `payload.id` were 1, and your `payload.data` was 1000, what value would you expect `state.byId.1` to contain?

Comment: `state.byId["1"]` would be `["1000"]`

if another action were to happen with `{ id: 1, data: 2000 }` then state would be:

`{ byId: { "1": ["1000", "2000"] } }`

However, I found the answer I believe... will type it up now.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the array exists first. If it does, add a new element.  If not, create a new array with one element (the new data from the action)

```
const initialState = {
  byId: {}
};

function addReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "RECEIVE_DATA":
      return {
        ...state,
        byId: {
          ...state.byId,
          [action.payload.id]: (
              state.byId[action.payload.id] ? [
              ...state.byId[action.payload.id],
              action.payload.data
            ] : [action.payload.data])
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default addReducer;
```

You can read more about ternary statements here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Thank you, very nice alternative to what I ended up going with. If you're going to downvote though, you should leave a comment as to why. I believe my answer is a fine alternative, but if there is a reason why its not ok I would like to know.

Comment: It doesn't do what the question says

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but I think you need something like this

```
 function addReducer(state = initialState, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "RECEIVE_DATA":
          return {
            ...state,
            byId: {
              ...state.byId,
              [action.payload.id]: 
                [action.payload.data]

            }
          };
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
```

Comment: This will overwrite whatever data is already there. The idea is to append any new data to an existing array if it's there

Answer (score -1):

The answer to this problem lies in flattening the state. I am sure there are other ways to fix this problem, but I found this the cleanest.

Typically the `byId` property of state is created through flattening state per the guidelines in [the docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape/)

I take it one step further, making the `byId` property an Array instead of an Object. I move the `id` into the objects of the array like in this new sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-zj1n4

I just have to remember the `byId` is now an array when I map the state to my components.

No functionality is lost and my `byId` field can now support multiple different ids if needed (e.g. if I had many to many relationships on the objects)

Here is the code:

in reducer

```
case "RECEIVE_DATA":
      return {
        ...state,
        byId: [...state.byId, action.payload.data]
      };
```

new action:

```
export function action() {
  return {
    type: RECEIVE_DATA,
    payload: {
      data: {
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 2),
        value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)
      }
    }
  };
}
```